# Printable characters in a binary file

Tags: linux, command-line

Strings cmd prints the printable characters in a binary file.
what does this printable character actually mean.. I mean the code from which the binary was made was itself printable.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please clarify the question? It has already two close votes.

Comment: What did you learn when you did `man strings` ?

Comment: "Binary" does not just mean executable. Database table contents, and many application data files, are a mix of binary (integer and float) along with text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readable code has been converted into machine code, and the comments have been removed by the preprocessor.

However, literal strings in the program like `"Hello, World!"` are still there for use at run-time. Also, the names of symbols like function names and variable names are contained in a table for use by debug tools, unless they have been removed with the `strip` utility. The names of dynamic code libraries are also present.

Most of my C programs contain their own man page, which can be shown with a -H option. So `strings` would also report the whole man page, plus every print format string, error message etc. and a list of all library calls, like `strcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5`.